# HttpClient PCL Cookies Not Being Applied to Requests

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using .NET HttpClient for PCL (2.2.15) for a common library across Windows Phone 8, Windows 8, and .NET 4.5.  However, I don't see cookies being applied to requests.

I'm setting up the HttpClient and HttpClientHandler using the following code.  HttpClient is a property on the wrapping class.

```
CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    CookieContainer = CookieContainer,
    Credentials = client.CredentialCache,
    UseCookies = true,
    AutomaticDecompression = 
          DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
};

HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler, false);
```

Requests are being sent using the following.

```
var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

I'm able to peek into the CookieContainer on the handler when stepping through in Debug and am able to see the CookieContainer for the domain I'm working against with the expected cookie.

The cookie has the following values:

- Path = '/'
- Domain = '.staging3.api.com'
- Value = [authentication_id]
- Name = 'API_AuthId'

The subsequent request is roughly: `https://staging3.api.com/api/v3/Items`

I've also tried setting the cookie myself, however `CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(requestUri)` returns an empty string.

Additional information:

If I modify the requestUri to `https://www.staging3.api.com/api/v3/Items` I'm able to get the cookie header from `CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(requestUri)`

Comment: You're probably hitting this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/478521/cookiecontainer-domain-handling-issue

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer.  Definitely seems to be it. I've already added in the fun (horrible) hack.